# Debugging DLL which is invoked from another DLL

Tags: dll, visual-studio-debugging

Can you help me out providing me the solution for following problem .

I have a 1.DLL which we wrote for windows service framework ,from it we are invoking one more 2.DLL . My 1.DLL will be invoked by any  applications which use the service framework.

Will there be a possibility to debug by 2.dll ?

Thank You

Comment: Did you write the second dll?

Comment: yes ..i have the code for 2.dll also and both the dlls are un managed code Dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint on the entry into 2.dll, it will prompt for the location of the code and you can browse to this and go through the same as any normal project.

**Update**. You added this is unmanaged code. I have not tried for unmanaged, but in theory it should be the same as long as you have the source code.

Comment: my 1.dll will be invoked by a Text Service , which we can not debug by using local debugger .

Comment: You need to attach the debugger to 'something' unfortunately. If you have coded the software well, you would have tracing code in there anyway and could enable this to at least get an understanding of what is going on.